# Job is Running but is not visible in artisan schedule:list

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I originally scheduled a couple of jobs to run, but then removed them from the Kernel. Yet, they are still running and they do not show up in the list of scheduled jobs! I know they are running because they fail and I log the name of the job in my logs before it runs as Log::info. This is driving me nuts. I am using Laravel Vapor. What am I missing?

The jobs that are running are called AutoSendFaxWithEncounter and AutoSendFaxWithReferral
[running jobs but not in scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii5M0.png)

Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use DB;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
       Commands\ProcessFiles::class, 
       Commands\ImportCustomerFills::class, 
       Commands\ImportCustomerEncounters::class, 
       Commands\ImportCustomerReferrals::class, 
       Commands\IndexFills::class, 
       Commands\IndexEncounters::class,
       Commands\IndexReferrals::class,  
       Commands\CreateS3Directories::class,
       Commands\FilterFills::class, 
       Commands\InsertPatients::class, 
       Commands\InsertPharmacies::class, 
       Commands\InsertProviders::class, 
       Commands\InsertProducts::class, 
      
  
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        
        $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\IncomingFaxage(3))
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
        
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\UpdateFaxageStatus(3))
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
        
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\StoreInboundS3())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
        
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\StoreOutboundS3())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
        
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\InsertProducts())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
        
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\InsertPatients())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
        
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\InsertProviders())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
            
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\InsertPharmacies())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);

            /*
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\InsertClaims())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
            */
            
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\InsertEncounterLocations())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);

            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\IndexFills())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
            
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\IndexEncounters())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);

            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\IndexReferrals())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);

            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\IndexEncounterLocations())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
            
            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\FilterFills())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);

            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\NpiRegistry())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);

            $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\RunImports())
            ->everyFiveMinutes()->environments(['production','local','staging']);
      
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

```
artisan schedule:list
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Command | Interval    | Description                       | Next Due                   |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\IncomingFaxage           | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\UpdateFaxageStatus       | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\StoreInboundS3           | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\StoreOutboundS3          | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\InsertProducts           | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\InsertPatients           | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\InsertProviders          | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\InsertPharmacies         | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\InsertEncounterLocations | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\IndexFills               | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\IndexEncounters          | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\IndexReferrals           | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\IndexEncounterLocations  | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\FilterFills              | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\NpiRegistry              | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
|         | */5 * * * * | App\Jobs\RunImports               | 2021-07-28 15:35:00 +00:00 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue myself. This was deceiving, and it is  not documented well in vapor documentation. My issue was my deployment yaml file and using the same custom queue names between production and staging project environments. What I was seeing were jobs running in an alternative environment but in the same queue.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You need to check with Vapor UI.

New open-source package: Vapor UI. In short, this package provides a beautiful dashboard within your Vapor powered application that allows you to monitor your application's logs and failed queue jobs.

Here you can check all the things related to job and scheduling.

```
composer require laravel/vapor-ui


php artisan vapor-ui:install
```

For more information please check below url.

https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/introduction.html#installing-the-vapor-ui-dashboard